# Java Program Class and Tester

Tags: java

Can you help me with my assignment please

Write a program to test the Person class defined below. Your test program should create two
instances of the class (each to test a different constructor) and test each of the methods. You are
also required to illustrate the error in trying to access private data members from the client class
(for clarity temporarily change the private modifier to public and test again). See screenshots
below for sample output.

The screen shots are displayed as:

```
p1 name = Not Given Age = 0 Gender = U
p2 name = Jane Doe Age = 0 Gender = F
p1 name = John Doe Age = 25 Gender = M
```

and

```
PersonTester.jave:20: name has private access in Person
            System.out.println("p2 name = " + p2.name + "Age = " + p2.age + "Gender = " + p2.gender);

PersonTester.jave:20: age has private access in Person
            System.out.println("p2 name = " + p2.name + "Age = " + p2.age + "Gender = " + p2.gender);

PersonTester.jave:20: gender has private access in Person
            System.out.println("p2 name = " + p2.name + "Age = " + p2.age + "Gender = " + p2.gender);

3 errors
```

Here is the class given

```
class Person {

    // Data Members 
    private String name; // The name of this person
    private int age; // The age of this person
    private char gender; // The gender of this person

    // Default constructor
    public Person() {
        name = "Not Given";
        age = 0;
        gender = 'U';
    }

    // Constructs a new Person with passed name, age, and gender parameters.
    public Person(String personName, int personAge, char personGender) {
    name = personName;
    age = personAge;
    gender = personGender; 
    } 

    // Returns the age of this person.
    public int getAge( ) {
        return age;
    }

    // Returns the gender of this person.
    public char getGender( ) {
        return gender;
    }

    // Returns the name of this person.
    public String getName( ) {
        return name;
    }

    // Sets the age of this person.
    public void setAge( int personAge ) {
        age = personAge;
     }

    // Sets the gender of this person.
    public void setGender(char personGender) {
        gender = gender;
    }

    // Sets the name of this person.
    public void setName( String personName ) {
        name = personName;
    }

} // end class
```

And here is what I have done

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Person_Tester { 

static char gender;

    public static void main(String [] args){ 

        //Create Array
        Person[] p1 = new Person[2]; 
        Person[] p2 = new Person[1];

      try(Scanner string_input = new Scanner(System.in); 
         Scanner int_input = new Scanner(System.in)) {

        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) { 

            Person person1 = new Person(); 

            Person person2 = new Person();

            //Enter Details For Person1

            System.out.println("Name: "); 

            person1.setName(string_input.nextLine()); 

            System.out.println("Age: "); 

            person1.setAge(string_input.nextInt()); 

            System.out.println("Gender: "); 

            gender = string_input.next().charAt(0);

            System.out.println(); 

            //Enter Details For Person2 

            System.out.println("Name: "); 

            person2.setName(string_input.nextLine()); 

            System.out.println("Age: "); 

            person2.setAge(string_input.nextInt()); 

            System.out.println("Gender: "); 

            gender = string_input.next().charAt(0);  

            System.out.println(); 

            string_input.close();
            int_input.close();

        }

      }//end for loop 

    }//end main method

}//end class
```

Ok sorry for wording my question wrong the last time

when I run the code this is what I get

```
Name: 
John Doe
Age: 
22
Gender: 
M

Name: 
Age: 
21
Gender: 
F

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalStateException: Scanner closed
    at java.util.Scanner.ensureOpen(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.Scanner.findWithinHorizon(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.Scanner.nextLine(Unknown Source)
    at Person_Tester.main(Person_Tester.java:26)
Name:
```

I've tried taking out

```
string_input.close();
int_input.close();
```

and I get

```
Name: 
john doe
Age: 
22
Gender: 
m

Name: 
Age: 
21
Gender: 
f

Name: 
Age: 
21
Gender: 
f

Name: 
Age: 
23
Gender: 
m

Name: 
Age:
```

it stays running and won't let me enter in a name

Can you help me fix it please, I need to have it finished by 1pm

Comment: Regarding your question, `"Is what I have done correct and if not could someone please help me"` -- You should know this already by testing your code, and when you do this, does it work? If not, debug it first and find your errors before coming here.

Comment: Re your latest edit to your question:  `"An error is coming up could someone help me"` -- please post the complete error message for us and indicate which line is causing it.

Comment: Listen, you will want to first read the [help] and [tour] links before preceding further as your question problems are showing us that you've asked this question before seeing how this site works. Please check the links before re-editing this question.

Comment: i only tagged C++ because it came up in suggestions

Comment: Nuked the eclipse tag, since the problem has nothing to do with the IDE in use. @Shaunagh, please read [this tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/accesscontrol.html). Take some time to think things through and the solution to the error messages should become clear. Remember that it's not illegal to conduct an internet search to see if you can find the answer to your own problem -- professional developers do it all the time (that's how they stay professional developers).

Comment: Thank you for the new information. Now your question is answerable.

Comment: *"Your test program should create two instances of the class (each to test a different constructor)"* You do 3 instances 3 times in a loop but use only 1 constructor ever. I also don't think you are supposed to use `Scanner`, simply hardcode values. `Scanner` has no method to get a `char` that is required for `setGender` so you would have to do something like `person1.setGender(string_input.next("[a-zA-Z]").charAt(0))` which I doubt you're expected to understand.

Answer (score 0):

The error message is correct as the Scanner object does not in fact have a `nextAt()` method. It has `.next()`, `.nextInt()`, `.nextLine()`, `.nextDouble()`,... but no `.nextAt()`. The key here being when you run into a similar problem, check the Java API to see what methods **are** available. Here's a link to the [Scanner API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html) section which will show you all methods/constructors and such that are available to the Scanner object.

Compilers are very rigorous and unforgiving and will not allow made-up methods, and so we as coders are forced to be rigorous as well.

Comment: Ok sorry about that and thanks for your help, that's what our lecturer told us to use. So I've changed it to .next() but now I get the error message in the same lines "The method setGender(char) in the type person is not applicable for the arguments (String)"

Comment: @Shaunagh: the error message is telling you exactly what's wrong, and you've got your code in front of you, so you can see what `setGender(...)` accepts. You need to pass in a char, and so will need to use a method from the String class that returns a char. Check the String API.